# File_get_html url variable from input search FORM

Tags: php, forms

I have this code to retrieve a `<table>` content with `id="item_specification"`:

```
$html = file_get_html("http://www.example.com/product-link.html");
$result = $html->find('table[id=item_specification]');
echo $result[0];
```

That works without problem.
Now I need to **"dynamize"** this process through a search submitted in an input form:

```
<FORM method="post" action="http://www.example.com/search.html">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" name="search-field" id="header-search-field">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</FORM>
```

After submitted the input text form, it redirect me to another page, for example:

```
http://www.example.com/product-link-5.html
```

Now the result link, should be inserted in the `file_get_html($result_link_searched)` and used to perform the operations to find the `item_specification table` like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<FORM method="post" action="http://www.example.com/process.php">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" name="search-field" id="header-search-field">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</FORM>
```

process.php

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_html("http://www.example.com/".$_POST['search-field']);
    $result = $html->find('table[id=item_specification]');
    echo $result[0];
```

Comment: When I click the submit button, it only do a redirection to the action form page.